# Is this question really not for this site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, specific-question

I had to reword [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14446/what-to-do-with-old) several times before the site would allow me to ask it. Is it really not appropriate for this site? If yes, why not? If no, Is is possible for the qualifications for a question to be valid to be changed?

EDIT: The original question was something like this: What do you do with old ציצית that do not fit anymore? Can you throw them out? Should they be put in shemot?

Comment: Can you give some examples of your previous tries so we can better evaluate the issue?

Comment: A copy of the text of the error message would also be helpful

Comment: Without knowing the details as sought by the above comments, I'm going to assume this is the intended behavior, as explained in yydl's good answer; I'm tagging this [meta-tag:status-bydesign] at least until further details are edited in.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what the previous versions were, or what the error message said, I will venture a guess. Many times the system tries to weed out questions with little content. For example, if the original question looked like:

> **What to do with old ציצית**
>
> What do you do with old ציצית?

It probably would not accept it. As I explain [in the conversation over here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=2201733#2201733) (not that I'm much of an expert) about a similar situation where the questioner was trying to ask why we read koheles on sukkos:

> The body [of a question] should be more than [just the question itself]. Perhaps provide a brief explanation as to what Koheles is. Specify when we read Koheles (i.e. which day and when). Or any other information you may find relevant, that you as the "asker" already know. The key is to come up with a way of making your question meaningful on its own...

By changing around the question you eventually convinced the system that you were asking a "question of substance" which caused the post to go through.

Comment: This system gave me a hassle once when I tried to edit a very old post which was about as simply put as your example here.